# jQuery: attach a handler to the browser's native autocomplete selection

Tags: jquery, event-handling

I'm working on a form that calls a function whenever the value of a text field changes. It uses the "keyup" and "change" events for this. But if a user double-clicks the text field and then clicks on an item in their browser's built-in list of previously entered values, the function doesn't get called. The user has to click outside of the text field after that in order for the "change" event to be triggered. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you want the browser's autocomplete on that input? If not, you can set `autocomplete=false` and avoid the problem altogether.

Comment: It is `autocomplete=off` actually. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/How_to_Turn_Off_Form_Autocompletion

Comment: `autocomplete=false` works in webkit, but good to know.

Comment: That's a good idea, but, in my case, it would be good to keep the autocomplete functionality. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can listen for `focus` and `blur` events on the input like so:

```
function monitor() {
 console.log($('#input').val()); // Log the value (or trigger your chnage)
}

var timer = '';

$('#input').on('focus', function() {
  timer = setInterval(monitor, 100);
}).on('blur', function() {
  clearInterval(timer);
});
```

[Here's a working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eGWDs/).